# Is there a way to insert an intermediate UIViewController into your heirarchy to unwind to later?

Tags: ios

I have three view controllers in a Storyboard.

The user always starts out in View Controller A.

Most of the time, the user will transition to View Controller B, then to view controller C, then continuing on back and forth between B and C.

However, occasionally, a user will jump straight from A to C.  If this is the case, I would like to be able to unwind back to B once the user is done with C, but I can't figure out a way to insert B into the heirarchy for C to unwind back to it.  Using trickery to segue to B and then automatically call a segue from B to C is visually jarring, even if I turn animations off.

The only other option I can see for myself is designing B and C so that they can unwind to each other but that seems like it's going to require a lot of duplicate code and I'd rather avoid it if I can.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? More generally any info on how you are presenting your VCs could be helpful.

Comment: No navigation controller.  All three VCs have "Full screen" as their presentation, all the segues are of kind "Present Modally" with presentation set to "Same As Destination."

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a non-hackish way of solving this.

If NavigationController was used we can pop and push views to the stack from any child view controllers. That would work reasonably well.

With modal presentation its more difficult. I would set A as Delegate of C. After the user goes from A to C and wants to go "back". I would call the delegate method on A. A would segue to B. Then I would dismiss C. Something like that will work:

```
protocol CDelegate {
    func presentB()
}

class VCA: CDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "VC" {
            if let _vc = segue.destinationViewController as? VC {
                _vc.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }

    func presentB {
      self.present(VCB, animated: false) 
    }
}

class VC {

   weak var delegate: CDelegate!

   func dismiss() {
     delegate.presentB()
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

I have not tested this, so this might still cause jittering animations.